# Delete large amount of data on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I need to delete 900,000.00 million records in SQL Server.

I would like to know the best way.

I did the following SELECT.

```
DeleteTable: 
   DELETE TOP(1000)  TAB1 
   FROM TABLE1 TAB1 
     LEFT JOIN TABLE2 TAB2 ON TAB1.ID_PRODUCT = AB2.ID_PRODUCT 
   WHERE TAB2.ID_PRODUCT IS NULL; 
   IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 goto DeleteTable;
```

I would like to know if there is how I can optimize this query for better delete performance

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if an `EXISTS` condition would be faster than the outer join

Comment: `900,000.00 million`?!? How many is that?

Comment: @jarlh I'm guessing the OP means 9 million....

Comment: Why not just use `truncate`?

Comment: Any dependencies, like fk references etc?

Comment: @thisextendsthat : OP clearly needs a conditionnal delete. Truncate would clear all the table.

Comment: Copy the few remaining rows to a new table, and drop the current one.

Comment: Thank you guys,

How would Delete look like EXISTS?

Almost 1 Billion Records

There are no FKs

Answer (score 4):

Deleting 900,000,000 rows is going to take a long time and you might run out of temporary storage -- unless you have lots and lots of storage. Your approach of deleting rows in increments in one approach.

If your logging is not set to "simple", then you might want to consider that. With your incremental delete approach, that will at least prevent the log from filling up.

For your query, you want `tab2(id_product)` to have an index. I'm not sure if an index on `tab1(id_product)` would really help.

Another is just to recreate the table, because `insert`s and table creation is much more efficient.

For this, you can essentially do:

```
select t1.*
into temp_tab1
from tab1 t1 
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id_product = t1.id_product);

truncate table tab1;  -- back it up first!

insert into tab1
    select *
    from temp_tab1;
```

Note: If you have an identity column, you may want to set identity insert on. Also, if you have foreign key constraints *to* this table, then you need extra care.

Finally, if this is something that you need to do repeatedly, then you should consider partitioning the table. It is much more efficient to drop partitions than to delete rows.

Comment: You might also want to wrap the entire thing in a transaction with `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, if it's a live database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful if the database is highly transactional and the table has heavy read-write activity mainly because you may be blocking other sessions while delete is in  progress. A slower but less impactful approach is to use a cursor to delete the records. The way to do it is by throwing product_id into #table and deleting from the actual table using the product_id as a predicate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

This base has no high transactions.

So I could use something similar to my code above, I just don't know how to use it in the most performative way,
Would it be better with using JOIN, EXISTS or some other way?